# Azure Active directory Multi tenant authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm new in AAD B2C authentication. Currently I have three applications hosted on AAD and access my web API which is hosted on azure Active directory.
I'm moving one of the applications to B2C tenant. I've hosted the web API in B2C also and I'm using the below code in the startup class.

```
public partial class Startup
{
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
var settings = new SecurityTokenSettings();
var validAudiencesList = new List<String>
{
settings.GetValue("apiResource"),
settings.GetValue("apiClientId")
};
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
Tenant = settings.GetValue("tenant"),
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
ValidAudiences = validAudiencesList,
SaveSigninToken = true,
},
AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
});
app.UseClaimsAuthorization();
}
}
```

This works fine when I use the AAD registered application and Web API. In ClaimsAuthorization - context.Authentication.User has claims and User info.

But when I use the B2C registered app and web API, the user info in the context is empty. Also I don't see any claims.

If I use app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication, will I be successful with both AAD and B2C registered applications?

How do I authenticate AAD application and B2C application to access the web API.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to identify the exact problem without more code and your app config details, but I recommend you checkout the [Azure AD B2C .NET Web App to a Web API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) code sample.  This sounds like the scenario you're trying to implement.